# Как обрабатывать ответы от Rest сервера на базе Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Имеется entity City

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class City implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String region;
}
```

и к ней CityRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource()
public interface CityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<City, Long> {
    // @RestResource(path = "names") http://localhost:8080/people/search/names
    List<City> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

По запросу `http://localhost:8080/cities` выдается следующий самодокументируемый ответ в формате Json. Запрос делается из `org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.RestTemplate`

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "cities" : [ {
      "name" : "City1",
      "region" : "Region1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/1"
        },
        "city" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "City2",
      "region" : "Region2",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/2"
        },
        "city" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/2"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/cities"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Мне нужен только список entity City (возможно с полем Id).
Вопрос: Что делать с этой красотой?

1. Вырезать нужную мне часть средствами RestTemplate (я что-то пока там этих средств не увидел)
2. Создавать класс (с целым рядом подклассов) и загонять в него Jackson'ом ответ целиком?
3. Пытаться изменить дефолтную структуру Sping boot для выдачи ответов Rest 
   сервера?
   Пожалуйста, поделитесь своим опытом по этому вопросу. Можно ткуть носом в пример  в Интернете

Comment: вы используете spring data rest, можете сделать свой контроллер и возвращать то что надо

Comment: Пока в эту сторону смотреть не хотелось бы. Желаю помучиться на клиентской стороне :). По моему, должен быть какой то удобный способ обработки ответов Rest'a, которые  spring data rest выдает по-умолчанию (не зря же разработчики мучились. На втором месте в моих планах стоит подправить где-то в конфигах \ шаблонах формат выдаваемых ответов **по всем запросам**. А уж ручное написание контроллеров - на потом.